# AWS AUTHORIZATION endpoint redirecting to LOGIN endpoint

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-cognito

In AWS, I have a User Pool.

- That user pool has a user.
- That user pool has an App client, with App Client Id of MY-CLIENT-ID.
- That App client is enabled as an identity provider for the cognito user pool, has a callback url of https://MY_APP/redirect_uri, has only "Authorization code grant" checked under "Allowed OAuth Flows" and "email" and "openid" checked under "Allowed OAuth Scopes".
- That user pool has a domain name of MY-DOMAIN.

When I navigate to

```
https://MY-DOMAIN.auth.us-east-1.amazoncognito.com/login?
response_type=code&
client_id=MY-CLIENT-ID&
redirect_uri=https://MY_APP/redirect_uri
```

I am redirected to the default Cognito login screen, and can successfully authenticate with my User pool user.  After authenticating, I am redirected to

```
https://MY_APP/redirect_uri?code=AUTHORIZATION_CODE
```

However, when I navigate (either via browser or curl) to

```
https://MY-DOMAIN.auth.us-east-1.amazoncognito.com/oauth2/authorize?
response_type=code&
client_id=MY-CLIENT-ID&
redirect_uri=https://MY_APP/redirect_uri
```

where I expect

```
HTTP/1.1 302 Found
Location: https://MY_APP/redirect_uri?code=AUTHORIZATION_CODE
```

instead, I'm receiving

```
HTTP/1.1 302 Found
Location: https://MY-DOMAIN.auth.us-east-1.amazoncognito.com/login?
response_type=code&
client_id=MY-CLIENT-ID&
redirect_uri=https://MY_APP/redirect_uri
```

which (obviously) redirects me to the login page.

I'm certain I've overlooking something obvious, but cannot figure out what it is.

Ref: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cognito/latest/developerguide/authorization-endpoint.html

Answer (score 0):

Do you expect from Cognito to provide SSO? Apparently Cognito is not working that way.

As far I have my experience,  with new authentication request the user will be indeed redirected to the login form. If the user is already having a web session (cookie), there is option to continue with existing user session or reauthenticate.

After that (reauthenticatation) the user is redirected to the callback redirect_uri

Comment: I mean, not to be too snarky, I expect AWS cognito to work the way it's documented in the developer guide.  If AUTHORIZATION is only useful when a user has previously logged in and thus left their credentials in a cookie or the like, I'd like to know that.

Comment: @DrewStevens Cognito is working as documented, at the end the user is redirected to the callback (redirect_uri)  with an authorization code (or token). What happens inbetween is depending on the session, timeout, ... and I assume it may change over time, so the doc contains only fixed parts. What is your actual issue with that? (I'd assume you could have issues when trying to emulate user behaviour from backend..)

Comment: The example positive request for an authorization code grant in the documentation shows a request made to the authorize endpoint, and a response redirect to the redirect uri with the authorization code as a query parameter.

What I'm experiencing is a request to the authorize endpoint resulting in a response redirect to the login endpoint without the code as a query parameter; a behavior which is not documented, and the cause for which is unclear.